How to redirect output to both a file and stdout?
I have found multiple answers on the internet for variations on what I am after. None provide the exact solution.
Specifically, I have a function func, which internally runs a make process. I have no trouble redirecting the output of func to both stdout and a log file. However, I cannot get the output of the internal make to be present in both. It only appears on my terminal screen.
So far, I have tried:
func 2>&1 | tee output.file

This redirects make output to the output file, however it also causes undesired verbose logging to both the file and stdout.
I assume the extra output is ordinarily hidden as it is directed to stderr.
However, if I run:
func 1>&1 | tee output.file

No output from the child make command is directed to the output file.
I expect the solution to be a quick and easy one for someone that knows. Appreciatively.

First, make sure what goes where (e.g. try 1>stdout 2>stderr). Then you can decide where you want each part to go.

Try < <(func 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3) tee output.file

You might also what to try func 2> >(tee output.file) | cat

Thankyou for the comment Choroba and David. @DavidAnderson, could you please explain how your answers work ? Specifically, func 2> >(tee file) | cat.
I read it as:

Call func
redirect the output of func, defined by file descriptor 2
After this I am not sure. There is a blank space immediately following the redirect. How does Bash interpret this ?


The problem is unclear. First you say "I cannot get the output of the internal make to be present in both"; then you try something and "this redirects make output to the output file". I know how tee works: if something gets to the output file then it must get to the stdout of tee. So you can "get the output of the internal make to be present in both", right? Now the problem is with vague "undesired verbose logging". What is it exactly? Where does it come from? The question begs for mcve. Please [edit] and add one.

@KamilMaciorowski: I assumed make is writing to stderr and that the OP only wants stderr written to outfile.file.

After reading the posted question, I assumed make is writing to stderr and that the OP only wants stderr written to outfile.file. This answer was tested using GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release. Below is the proposed solution.
func 2> >(tee file) | cat

Note: Spaces are not permitted between the 2 and > characters or between the > and ( characters.
I do not know what exactly is in the OP's func. To test, I used the following definition for func.
func() { echo "stderr" >&2; echo "stdout"; }

Explaination
Basically, stderr from func is redirected to an anonymous fifo and tee is redirected to read stdin from the same fifo. The above solution could be simplified as shown below.
func 2> >(tee file) | cat

However, in testing the command prompt appeared before output from tee, as shown below.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ func 2> >(tee file)
stdout
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ stderr

To prevent this from happening, all stdout for both func and tee is piped though the cat command, as shown below.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ func 2> >(tee file) | cat
stdout
stderr
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 


To better understand what | cat does, the solution could be rewritten as shown below. I will not go as far as to say this is an exact equivalent to the solution, but if not, then it is very close.
(cat) < <(func 2> >(tee output.file))

Here one can see the subshell containing tee is nested inside the subshell containing func. The result is all stdout must be redirected to the the stdin of the subshell containing cat. Bash will not return a command prompt until after the cat command has completed.
Note: the above could be simplified with what is shown below. All stdout is written to an anonymous fifo and the name of this fifo is passed to cat as a single parameter. In this case, cat ignores stdin.
cat <(func 2> >(tee output.file))


References

Bash Redirections Cheat Sheet
This version does contain some errors. With respect to this answer, cmd1 | cmd2 contains some inaccuracies.
Bash Redirections Cheat Sheet
This version removed errors by omitting cmd1 | cmd2. Note: Both are stored in the same repository.

